# Unit Test Spring Integration flow DSL

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-boot-test

I am trying to unit test a simple flow where it is checking for existence of a file and then do some additional task.

IntegrationFlow

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow initiateAlarmAck() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("processAckAlarmInputChannel")
            .handle((payload, headers) ->  {
                LOG.info("Received initiate ack alarm request at " + payload);
                File watermarkFile = getWatermarkFile();
                if(watermarkFile.isFile()){
                    LOG.info("Watermark File exists");
                    return true;
                }else{
                    LOG.info("File does not exists");
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .<Boolean, String>route(p -> fileRouterFlow(p))
            .get();
}
File getWatermarkFile(){
    return new File(eventWatermarkFile);
}

@Router
public String fileRouterFlow(boolean fileExits){
    if(fileExits)
        return "fileFoundChannel";
    else
        return "fileNotFoundChannel";
}
```

There is another integration flow which pick a message from `fileNotFoundChannel` and does additional processing. I do not want to unit test this portion. How do I stop my test to not do further and stop after putting a message on `fileNotFoundChannel`?

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileNotFoundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("fileNotFoundChannel")
            .handle((payload, headers) ->  {
                LOG.info("File Not Found");
                return payload;
            })
            .handle(this::getLatestAlarmEvent)
            .handle(this::setWaterMarkEventInFile)
            .channel("fileFoundChannel")
            .get();
}
```

Unit Test Class

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(AcknowledgeAlarmEventFlow.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AlarmAPIApplication.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties ")
public class AcknowledgeAlarmEventFlowTest {


    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("processAckAlarmInputChannel")
    DirectChannel processAckAlarmInputChannel;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fileNotFoundChannel")
    DirectChannel fileNotFoundChannel;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fileFoundChannel")
    DirectChannel fileFoundChannel;

    @Mock
    File mockFile;

    @Test
    public void initiateAlarmAck_noFileFound_verifyMessageOnfileNotFoundChannel(){


        AcknowledgeAlarmEventFlow.ProcessAcknowledgeAlarmGateway gateway = applicationContext.getBean(AcknowledgeAlarmEventFlow.ProcessAcknowledgeAlarmGateway.class);
        gateway.initiateAcknowledgeAlarm();

        processAckAlarmInputChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Date()).build());
        MessageHandler mockMessageHandler = mock(MessageHandler.class);

        fileNotFoundChannel.subscribe(mockMessageHandler);
        verify(mockMessageHandler).handleMessage(any());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is exactly scenario what we are doing [now](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2148) with the `MockMessageHandler` implementation.

Looks like you go right way with mocking to prevent further action in that `fileNotFoundFlow`, but miss some simple tricks:

You have to `stop()` the real `.handle((payload, headers) )` endpoint on that `fileNotFoundChannel`. That way it will unsubscribe from the channel and won't consume messages any more. For this purpose I suggest to do:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from("fileNotFoundChannel")
.handle((payload, headers) ->  {
  LOG.info("File Not Found");
  return payload;
}, e -> e.id("fileNotFoundEndpoint"))
```

And in the test class

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("fileNotFoundEndpoint")
AbstractEndpoint fileNotFoundEndpoint;
 ...

@Test
public void initiateAlarmAck_noFileFound_verifyMessageOnfileNotFoundChannel(){
  this.fileNotFoundEndpoint.stop();

  MessageHandler mockMessageHandler = mock(MessageHandler.class);

  fileNotFoundChannel.subscribe(mockMessageHandler);


  AcknowledgeAlarmEventFlow.ProcessAcknowledgeAlarmGateway gateway = applicationContext.getBean(AcknowledgeAlarmEventFlow.ProcessAcknowledgeAlarmGateway.class);
  gateway.initiateAcknowledgeAlarm();

  processAckAlarmInputChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Date()).build());
  verify(mockMessageHandler).handleMessage(any());
}
```

Pay, please, attention, how I have moved mocking and subscribing before sending message to the channel.

With the new `MockIntegrationContext` features the Framework will take care about that stuff for you. But yeah... As with any unit test, the mocks must be prepared before interaction.

**UPDATE**

Working sample:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MockMessageHandlerTests {

@Autowired
private SubscribableChannel fileNotFoundChannel;

@Autowired
private AbstractEndpoint fileNotFoundEndpoint;

@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void testMockMessageHandler() {
    this.fileNotFoundEndpoint.stop();

    MessageHandler mockMessageHandler = mock(MessageHandler.class);

    this.fileNotFoundChannel.subscribe(mockMessageHandler);

    GenericMessage<String> message = new GenericMessage<>("test");
    this.fileNotFoundChannel.send(message);

    ArgumentCaptor<Message<?>> messageArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Message.class);

    verify(mockMessageHandler).handleMessage(messageArgumentCaptor.capture());

    assertSame(message, messageArgumentCaptor.getValue());
}

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public static class Config {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileNotFoundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("fileNotFoundChannel")
        .<Object>handle((payload, headers) -> {
            System.out.println(payload);
            return payload;
        }, e -> e.id("fileNotFoundEndpoint"))
        .channel("fileFoundChannel")
        .get();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Corrected the test and realized that "fileNotFoundChannel" was a direct channel. I changed "fileNotFoundChannel" to SubscribableChannel so that the testcase can have a mockMessageHandler subscribe to the channel. However the control does not come to verify line in the test case. I do see that preSend is called on 'fileNotFoundChannel'

Comment: I added fully working sample to my answer. Be sure that you have stopped endpoint before mocking. Otherwise your `fileNotFoundChannel` has several subscribers and the first one will catch the first message. See: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-implementations-directchannel about `LoadBalancingStrategy`

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I have a bunch of tests in a test class which test end points individually. They were running well when tested indivudially but when run in a single test class, some of them were failing. For every test that stops an end point, I had to start at the end of the test. Also, when a mock handler subscribes to a channel, I had to unsubscribe it at the end of the test. This was necessary for all tests to be run in a single test class.

Comment: That's true: if you subscribe mock, you have to unsubscribe in the end. That's why we have in our test framework `resetBeans()` option

Comment: Can we use `@SpringBootTest` with `@SpringIntegrationTest`? The docs have surprisingly omitted this.